# apt-get install always fail with "/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code"

Tags: linux, apt-get

My new Ubuntu16.04 always got those problems:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apport
 apport-gtk
 python-decorator
 python-pil:amd64
 python-imaging
 python-six
 python-scipy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

whenever I try to use the apt-get install, in the end, it came up with the above information. TAT

Help~~~~~
I can use it install anything. Orz

Comment: Use google please... the answer is out there...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info /var/lib/dpkg/info_old
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info 
sudo apt-get update, apt-get -f install 
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/* /var/lib/dpkg/info_old
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info 
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info_old /var/lib/dpkg/info
```

it did not work for me, so i install my system again TAT
Thank you everyone